# window.open(url) only open new window with raw text instead of downloading

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, blob

When I use the following method :

```
downloadFile(){
  const blob = this.b64toBlob(this.formGroup.value.attachment);
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url);
}
```

I'm expected it to open a new tab and download the file.

But it's only opening a new tab with raw text content inside.
[This is the result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSWnj.png).

But if I copy/paste the content of the page as an URL, it's working great and my download is starting as expected.

What am I suppose to do to start the download directly.

PS: this is the b64toBlob() method :

```
b64toBlob(b64Data: string, contentType = '', sliceSize = 512): Blob {
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  const byteArrays = [];

  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
}

  return new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after few more hours of research...

I managed to get this to work as expected.

Posting the answer if someone end up with the same issue :

```
downloadFile() {
 const blob = this.b64toBlob(this.formGroup.value.attachment);
 blob.text().then(result => { // waiting for blob content to be available... 
   const a: any = document.createElement('a');
   a.download = 'test.pdf'; // or whatever your file name is
   a.href = result;
   a.click();
 });
}
```

The line *a.download = 'test.pdf'* seem mandatory on chrome but working fine without it for Firefox.

Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using URL, create a href out of it and you can use the respective click function. Please change the below function of yours something like below and hopefully, you can download the file.

```
downloadFile(){
            var a: any = document.createElement("a");
            a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            const blob = this.b64toBlob(this.formGroup.value.attachment);
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.href = url;
            a.click();
        }
```

Sometimes this click won't work properly in IE. In that case you can use msSaveBlob function. The whole function can be changed like,

```
downloadFile() {
        var a: any = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        const blob = this.b64toBlob(this.formGroup.value.attachment);
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;

        var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!(<any>document).documentMode;

        if (isIE) {
            var retVal = navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, "test"+ '.txt');
        }
        else {
            a.download = "test" + '.txt';
        }
        a.click();
    }
```